# Cake PHP timezone wrong

Tags: cakephp, timezone

I got a strange problem with Cake. I live in Germany. When I add posts the time in the "created" database-field is 6 hours back. E.g. a post created 6pm shows up in the database as created 12am.
I use a managed server and I contacted the company which set the php.ini to the correct timezone Europe/Berlin. When I request the servers php.ini, it shows the timezone "Europe/Berlin" correctly. But when I run the code

```
$timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
echo "The current server timezone is: " . $timezone;
```

in CakePHP it shows

```
The current server timezone is: America/New_York
```

I already tried to set in the core.php:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
```

But that has no effect at all.
Hopefully someone knows what to do.

**EDIT 1:**

After asking the support to run "locale -a", following was spit out:

```
# locale -a
C
de_DE
de_DE@euro
de_DE.iso88591
de_DE.iso885915@euro
de_DE.utf8
deutsch
en_US.utf8
german
POSIX
```

I assume that serverside everything is fine and the error is cake-wise. 
But I don´t have a clue what to do next? Maybe someone can help. Thanks in advance.

** EDIT 2: **

After looking around what it could be I found the error in the bootstrap.php of the Usermanagement-plugin, which set the timezone there to UTC. So everything works fine now. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The problem was in a plugin which also had a config.php. There the Cake-config was overwritten. Now everything is fine.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:**

If doing the answer below has no effect (per OP), it could be [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909911/php-setlocale-has-no-effect):

> Is is quite likely that the German locale is not installed on the
>   server your running the script on - do you have shell access to the
>   server? Then try
>
> locale -a
>
> to see which locales are installed. Also have a look here Is
>   it feasible to rely on setlocale, and rely on locales being installed?

---

**TLDR:**

You had the right idea - just put it in your `Config/bootstrap.php`. instead of your `Config/core.php.`

**More Detail:**

This is likely the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13389315/cakephp-created-and-modified-server-time-offset-for-save).  It's answer:

> Put this in your Config/bootstrap.php:
>
> date_default_timezone_set('UTC');  //or whatever your timezone is
>
> It's just based on the server time and really has nothing to do with
>   CakePHP - so just change the default timezone with PHP, and you should
>   be good to go. 'created' and 'modified' will be based on the specified
>   timezone.

To reiterate, the "`created`" and "`modified`" fields ARE based on the server and really don't have much to do with CakePHP (which it sounds like you already assumed correctly).

A related item (just fyi to read up on) is [CakeTime::convert()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/time.html#CakeTime::convert), but in this case, is not what you'd want.

Comment: I´m sorry but there´s no effect :-(

Comment: @edit of Dave. Sadly I don´t have shell access but I will ask the support, if they´d do that for me. Thanks for your great help :-)

Comment: I´m back. The support-guy ran the command and the following was spit out: # locale -a
C
de_DE
de_DE@euro
de_DE.iso88591
de_DE.iso885915@euro
de_DE.utf8
deutsch
en_US.utf8
german
POSIX. So what to do now? I don´t have a clue at all

Answer (score 0):

Set in app_controller not in code.php

Comment: No, it´s 2.x. I´ll try Daves ideas. Thank you anyway :-)

Comment: Well, it shows the correct timezone in cake but the saved posts are still the wrong time. That lets assume the server has some issues with locale. I´ll come back and tell the response of the server-company.